# Странное поведение фрагментов при их смене

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

### ***Проблема***

У меня есть 5 фрагментов, а так же еще 2 фрагмента, которые находятся в одном из этих 5, в виде viewpager.
5 фрагментов переключаются с помощью bottomNavigationView

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() != view.getSelectedItemId()) {
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (menuItems.indexOf(item.getItemId()) > menuItems.indexOf(view.getSelectedItemId())) {
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_slide_left_anim, R.animator.fragment_slide_right_anim);//Выбор анимации
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_slide_right_exit_anim, R.animator.fragment_slide_left_exit_anim); //Выбор анимации

        } 
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_contacts:
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, contactsFragment);
                break;
            case R.id.action_cloud:
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, cloudFragment);
                break;
            case R.id.action_messages:
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, messagesFragment);
                break;
            case R.id.action_profile:
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, profileFragment);
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, settingsFragment);
                break;
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

А вот это переключение фрагментов в ViewPager.

```
private DialogsFragment dialogsFragment;
private ChannelsFragment channelsFragment;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, null);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    dialogsFragment = new DialogsFragment();
    channelsFragment = new ChannelsFragment();

    setupMessagesPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return view;
}

private void setupMessagesPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    MessagesPagerAdapter adapter = new MessagesPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(dialogsFragment, "Диалоги");
    adapter.addFragment(channelsFragment, "Каналы");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при переходе на других фрагменты с помощью BottomNavigationView все фрагменты оставались и не пересоздавались.

Viewpager работает отлично в самом начале, так как это первый фрагмент, а вот потом при переключючении на другой фрагмент и возврате снова в viewpager у меня пропадают мои данные в нем, а так же его пролистывание грубо говоря лагает.

Пальцем приходится проматываться и никакого эффект допролистывания нет. Я посмотрел в дебагере, кажется этот фрагмент все равно пересоздается.

---

Как мне это исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась! Я использовал getFragmentManager() в строчке инициализации адаптера

```
MessagesPagerAdapter adapter = new MessagesPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

А нужно использовать - `getChildFragmentManager();`